# What condition(s) on $X$ and $A$ can ensure the existence of an element $a\in A$ such that $d(x_0, a)=d(x_0, A) $?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, descriptive-set-theory

Let $(X, d) $ be metric space and $A\subset X$ and $x_0\in X$

Define $d(x_0, A) =\inf\{d(x_0, a) :a\in A\}$

> What condition(s) on $X$ and $A$ can ensure the existence of an element $a\in A$ such that $d(x_0, a)=d(x_0, A) $ ?

Can we take care of uniqueness as well?

---

Motivation:

Suppose $X$ is a Hilbert space and $A\subset X$ non empty closed convex set then for all $x_0\in X$ $\exists! a\in A$ such that $d(x_0,a) =d(x_0, A) $

[$X$ is reflexive and strictly convex
iff $ A\subset X$ non empty closed convex set in $X$ is a Chebyshev set](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3266663/977780).

---

Particular cases:

Suppose $(X,d)$ be any metric spaces $A\subset X$ non empty compact set then $\forall x_0\in X, \exists a\in A$ such that $d(x_0, a) =d(x_0, A) $

Sketch:

$d_{x_0}:X\to\Bbb{R}$ is continuous and $A\subset X$ compact implies $\inf\{d(x_0, a) :a\in A\}$ is attained in A.

---

Going deep into the proof:

$d(x_0, A)=\inf\{d(x_0, a) :a\in A\}$ implies $\exists (a_n) \in A$ such that $d(x_0, a_n) \to d(x_0, A) $

$\lim _{n\to\infty}d(x_0, a_n)= d(x_0, A) $

Implies $ d(x_0,\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n)= d(x_0, A) $

> We only need to make sure that $(a_n)\subset A$ converges to $a\in A$ for some $a\in A$

$$\text{OR}$$

> $(a_n) $ has a convergent subsequence in $A$

Further treatment:

$(X, d) $ complete and $A\subset X$ non empty closed totally bounded set.

But no improvement at all! (Complete and totally boundedness $\iff$ compact.)

Comment: A slightly weaker condition is $A\cap B$ compact for any bounded set $B$. For example, $\mathbb N$ is not compact but its intersection with  any bounded set is.

Comment: I don't think you can find a general useful condition. For example say $X=\mathbb{R}^n$. Now fix a point $v_0$ of norm $1$. Then for any $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ outside of the unit disk we will have $d(0,A\cup\{v_0\})=d(0,v_0)$. So, this condition is extremely weak. It would be more interesting if it would hold for all $x_0$.

Comment: If $A$ is closed then we can guarantee the existence of $a\in A$ satisfying the condition, no? What I am missing?

Comment: @DanielHuff what about $X = [0,1) \cup \{2\}$ with the induced metric from $\mathbb{R}$ and $A = [0,1)$? Then $d(2, A) = 1$ but there is no $a$ such that $d(2, a) = 1$.

Comment: Along the same lines as @geetha290krm's comment, if $x_0$ varies then a necessary condition is for $A$ to be closed, and a sufficient condition is to have $A \cap \overline{B}$ compact for closed balls $\overline{B}$. So if $X$ is such that its closed balls are compact ($\implies$ $X$ is complete, but not equivalent) then it is necessary and sufficient that $A$ be closed.

Comment: The question is too general to be answerable, in this generality, the only reasonable answer is "sometimes yes, sometimes not." See also my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529828/infinite-dimensional-normed-spaces-and-the-distance/529903#529903) in the context of closed linear subspaces of Banach spaces.